# Infinite iterator

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I'm tring to do a for loop inside a infinite while loop. This infinite loop get data of 3 different index from ElasticCloud to operate it after. I'm trying to put conditions over the second loop but it turns infinite.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
while(True):
  datetime_BO = datetime.now(tz_BO) #Date of today

  ed_data1 = ed.DataFrame(es, "_index_1").tail(2) #Get last data of index 1 
  ed_data2 = ed.DataFrame(es, "_index_2").tail(2) #Get last data of index 2

  panda_data1 = ed.eland_to_pandas(ed_data1) #Converting to pandas
  panda_data2 = ed.eland_to_pandas(ed_data2)
  panda_data1 = panda_data1.sort_values(by="@timestamp") #Sort by date
  panda_data2 = panda_data2.sort_values(by="@timestamp")
  panda_data1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #Index date
  panda_data2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
  panda_data1 = panda_data1.groupby(panda_data1.index // 2).mean() #Mean this measure
  panda_data2 = panda_data2.groupby(panda_data2.index // 2).mean()

  i = 5
  list_n = [] #Empty list
  n = 0
  while n < i:
    ed_data3 = ed.DataFrame(es, "heartbeat-*").tail(4) #Getting last data of this index
    panda_data3 = ed.eland_to_pandas(ed_data3) #Converting to pandas
    panda_data3 = panda_data3.sort_values(by="@timestamp") #Sorting by date
    panda_data3 = panda_data3[panda_data3['field_1'].isin(['Yes','No'])] #Getting in the column "field_1" all values with "Yes" or "No"
    panda_data3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #New index
    status = panda_data3.iloc[:,1] #Lock the "field_1" column
    if status[0] == "down" and status[1] == "No": #If in field_1 column there is a "No", give a 0
      uptime = 0
    elif status[0] == "up" or status[1] == "Yes": #If in field_1 column there is a "No", give a 1
      uptime = 1
    else:
      pass
    list_n.append(int(uptime)) #Data for empty list
    time.sleep(5) #Wait 5 secs
    n+=1
    print(list_n)
```

What I'm getting with `i = 10` is this

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I need this exit from loop after complete the condition `n = i` and continue getting other data, but it gets in an eternal loop.

Any idea what I'm doing worng?

Edit 1:

I tried to use `break` after

```
    n += 1
    print(list_n)
  break
```

But now, the infinite `while(true)` is not working.

Comment: your outer loop runs infinite, set a condition to break out of it. Your condition`n<i` is only for your 2nd loop.

Comment: Thank you. :)
I was doing it in a worng way.

Answer (score 2):

just add a second break after the end of the second while, in the indentation of the first

```
    n+=1
    print(list_n)
break
```